# how print parse-tree using python2 runtime with antlr4

Tags: python-2.7, antlr4

I'm trying to use [antlr4 version 4.4](http://www.antlr.org/download/antlr-4.4-complete.jar) and the [python2 runtime](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Python+Target). The grammar is from the antlr4 book, page 6, file: *Hello.g4*:

```
grammar Hello;           
r  : 'hello' ID ;
ID : [a-z]+ ;
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

and I generate lexer and parser with command

```
antlr4 -Dlanguage=Python2 Hello.g4
```

the files *HelloLexer.py*, *HelloParser.py* and *HelloListener.py* among other, are then generated. I make a main program test.py to test the generated python parser:

```
from antlr4 import *
from HelloLexer import HelloLexer
from HelloParser import HelloParser

def main(argv):
    input = FileStream(argv[1])
    lexer = HelloLexer(input)
    stream = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
    parser = HelloParser(stream)
    tree = parser.r()
    print tree.toStringTree(parser)        <= the problem is here!

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    main(sys.argv)
```

Everything seems works ok, except that I can't print the parse tree.

```
C:\Users\LG\antlr\tpantlr2-code\code\install>Test.py data.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LG\antlr\tpantlr2-code\code\install\Test.py", line 15, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\LG\antlr\tpantlr2-code\code\install\Test.py", line 11, in main
    print tree.toStringTree(parser)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\antlr4\RuleContext.py", line 181, in toStringTree
    return Trees.toStringTree(self, ruleNames=ruleNames, recog=recog)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\antlr4\tree\Trees.py", line 48, in toStringTree
    s = escapeWhitespace(cls.getNodeText(t, ruleNames), False)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\antlr4\tree\Trees.py", line 68, in getNodeText
    return ruleNames[t.getRuleContext().getRuleIndex()]
TypeError: 'HelloParser' object does not support indexing
```

I haven't figured out yet what the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you took the wrong `toStringStree` function.

Take a look at the [java docs](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/tree/Trees.html#toStringTree(org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.Tree,%20org.antlr.v4.runtime.Parser)).

This explains the error message "object does not support indexing". The function you chose expects a list of rule names and not the parser.

Comment: I see now, I shall call i like this: print tree.toStringTree(),

Answer (score 8):

Oddly, toStringTree is a class method in the Python runtimes. You can call it like this to get the lisp style parse tree including stringified tokens:

```
from antlr4 import *
from antlr4.tree.Trees import Trees
# import your parser & lexer here

# setup your lexer, stream, parser and tree like normal

print(Trees.toStringTree(tree, None, parser))

# the None is an optional rule names list
```