# Python ANTLR4 example - Parser doesn't seem to parse correctly

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, antlr, antlr4, grammar

To demonstrate the problem, I'm going to create a simple grammar to merely detect Python-like variables.

I create a *virtual environment* and install [`antlr4-python3-runtime`](https://pypi.org/project/antlr4-python3-runtime/) in it, as mentioned in "[Where can I get the runtime?](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/python-target.md#where-can-i-get-the-runtime)":

[image: Install antlr4-python3-runtime]

Then, I create a `PyVar.g4` file with the following content:

```
grammar         PyVar;

program:        IDENTIFIER+;

IDENTIFIER:     [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*;

NEWLINE:        '\n' | '\r\n';

WHITESPACE:     [ ]+ -> skip;
```

Now if I test the grammar with `grun`, I can see that the grammar detects the variables just fine:

[image: Testing the grammar with grun]

Now I'm trying to write a parser in Python to do just that. I generate the Lexer and Parser, using this command:

```
antlr4 -Dlanguage=Python3 PyVar.g4
```

And they're generated with no errors:

[image: antlr4 -Dlanguage=Python3 PyVar.g4]

But when I use the example provided in "[How do I run the generated lexer and/or parser?](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/python-target.md#how-do-i-run-the-generated-lexer-andor-parser)", I get no output:

[image: Python parser produces nothing]

What am I not doing right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here.

**1. The grammar**:

In the line where I had,

```
program:        IDENTIFIER+;
```

the parser will only detect one or more variables, and it will not detect any newline. The output you see when running `grun` is the output created by the lexer, that's why newlines are present in the tokens. So I had to replace it with something like this, for the parser to detect newlines.

```
program:        (IDENTIFIER | NEWLINE)+;
```

**2. Printing the output of parser**

In `PyVar.py` file, I created a tree with this line:

```
tree = parser.program()
```

But it didn't print its output, nor did I know how to, but the [OP's comment on this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25136463/how-print-parse-tree-using-python2-runtime-with-antlr4?rq=1#comment39129827_25137278) suggests using `tree.toStringTree()`.

Now if we fix those, we can see that it works:

[image: Works!]